# Python Pandas group by then filter on condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying to first group by `id` then count for each `id`, how many rows have `score` > `avg`.

dataframe:

```
id col1  avg  score
a   1     3    3
a   0     4    3
a   1     3    5
b   1     2    4
b   1     4    5
```

want:

```
id score>avg total
a    1       3
b    2       2
```

my code:

```
df2 = df.groupby('id', as_index=False)[['score'] > ['avg']].agg({'score>avg': 'count', 'total': 'count'})
```

error i got:

```
KeyError: 'Column not found: False'
```

i am not sure what i should edit the `[['score'] > ['avg']]` portion to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is first create a column of boolean values that indicate whether score is greater than average and then group by 'id' and `sum` and `count` that new column.

```
df['score_gt_avg'] = df.score > df.avg
df.groupby('id')['score_gt_avg'].agg([('score>avg', 'sum'),('total', 'count')])

    score>avg  total
id                  
a         1.0      3
b         2.0      2
```

Equivalently you can also do in one line:

```
df.score.gt(df.avg).groupby(df.id).agg([('score>avg', 'sum'),('total', 'count')])
```